# If H(b) $\leq$ b then $\int_0^k (v-b)h(b) - [1-H(b)]db \leq \int_0^k (v-b) - [1-b]db $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, auction-theory

$H$ is a CDF over $[0,1]$

I want to prove that if $H(b) \leq b$ then :

$$\int_0^k (v-b)h(b) - [1-H(b)]db \leq \int_0^k (v-b) - [1-b]db $$ for all $k \in [0,1]$

I think this is true, but a rigorous proof does seem difficult to me. Can anyone help me to prove this? or does any theorem helps?

Comment: What is $v$ ? Is the inequality $ H(b) \leqslant b$ valid for all $b\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: $v∈[0,1]$ is a constant. And yes. $H(b)⩽b$ valid for all $b∈[0,1]$

Comment: And  $h(b)=H′(b)$

Comment: @JinsooBae I went out to solve some personal stuff, I'll update my answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $h(b)=H'(b)$ is a density, $v$ is a constant and $H(b) \leq b \quad\forall b$
\begin{align}
&H(b) \leq b \implies H(b)-1 \leq b-1 \implies 1-H(b)\geq1-b \implies -(1-H(b))\leq-(1-b) 
\end{align}

Substituting in the equation you get the following inequality.

$\int_0^k (v-b)h(b) - [1-H(b)]db \leq \int_0^k (v-b)h(b) - [1-b]db$

Now we need to show that substituting $h(b)$ for $1$ gives us the desired inequality.
We know that $\int_0^k(v-b)db = vk -\frac{k^2}{2}$ then:

\begin{align}
\int_0^k (v-b)h(b)db &= v\int_0^kh(b)db-\int_0^kbh(b)db\\
&= v[H(k)-H(0)]-\int_0^kbh(b)db\\
&= v(H(k)-H(0))-bH(b)|_0^k +\int_0^kH(b)db\\
&\leq(v-k)H(k)-H(0)v +\int_0^kbdb\\
&H(b)\leq b\; \forall b\; \wedge \text{H(.) is a cdf}\implies H(0)=0 \\
&\leq (v-k)k+\frac{k^2}{2}\\
&=vk-\frac{k^2}{2}
\end{align}
then the following holds whenever $v \geq k$
$$\int_0^k (v-b)h(b)db \leq vk-\frac{k^2}{2} = \int_0^k(v-b)db$$

Comment: A distribution function is bounded by 1 but a density function is not necessarily bounded by 1.

Comment: Well pointed, thanks, can we define boundaries just from the above information?

Comment: @Sergio Andrade $h(b)$ is the slope of the density, so it can be arbitrarily high at a narrow interval.

Comment: @mfl That is exactly what I want to prove. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: @Sergio Andrade Thank you for helping me. One possible error that I noticed is $-b H(b) | _0^k  \leq - k^2$ shouldn't be reversed?

Comment: @JinsooBae Yes, I corrected it, thanks for the feedback! I think now we really did it.

Comment: Perfect. Now I know that this hold whenever $(v-k) >0$. Since you used  $(v−k)H(k) \leq (v−k)k$. I guess if $v-k<0$, the inequality may not hold, but what you gave me is enough for my initial intention for this question.

Comment: However it seems that this holds just for $v \geq k$.

Comment: Yeah, we commented at the same time hahah

Comment: @Sergio Andrade Thank you so much. I want to give you 100 upvotes if I can. haha

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that

$$\int_0^k ((v-b)h(b) - (1-H(b)))db \leq \int_0^k ((v-b) - (1-b))db$$ if and only if

$$\int_0^k ((v-b)h(b) + H(b))db \leq \int_0^k ((v-b) +b)db$$ or equivalently

$$\int_0^k ((v-b)h(b) + H(b))db \leq \int_0^k vdb.$$

We will work with the LHS. We have

$$\int_0^k ((v-b)h(b) + H(b))db =vH(k)+\int_0^k(H(b)-bh(b))db.$$

Now, using integration by parts, it is

$$\int_0^kbh(b)db=[bH(b)]_0^k-\int_0^kH(b)db=kH(k)-\int_0^kH(b)db.$$ Thus

$$\int_0^k ((v-b)h(b) + H(b))db =vH(k)-kH(k).$$ On the other hand, the RHS is

$$\int_0^k vdb=vk.$$ So, the given inequality is equivalent to

$$vH(k)-kH(k)\le kv.$$ In other words

$$-kH(k)\le v(k-H(k)).$$ Now we see that

$$-kH(k)\le 0 \le v(k-k)\le v(k-H(k)),$$ where we have used $H(k)\le k \implies-k\le -H(k).$

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I noticed the integration by part is incorrect (as in the other question). But it helps me to understand the question better. Thank you!!